# How do I center list items horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have an excerpt of code that I need centered in my header, (just the text and the actual padding). I'm new to coding so if this doesn't sound right don't be surprised. This is the code where I need my list items centered in. Try to make your answer as beginner-like as possible.

CSS:

```
#navcontainer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #800000;
}
#navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#navcontainer ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 40px;
}
#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #800000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id= "navcontainer">

<!-- BEGIN TABS -->
<ul>
    <a id="index" class="page-logo" href="/">
    <img src="slamlogo.png" alt="Logo">
    <li><a href="/Jackpot">Jackpot</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Market">Market</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Support">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know the `li` elements are messy but I do it so I can see it better. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `text-align: center` to the `<ul>`:

```css
#navcontainer ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
#navcontainer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #800000;
  text-align: center;
}
#navcontainer ul li {
  display: inline;
}
#navcontainer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 40px;
}
#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #800000;
}
```

```html
<div id="navcontainer">
  <!-- BEGIN TABS -->
  <a id="index" class="page-logo" href="/">
    <img src="slamlogo.png" alt="Logo">
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/Jackpot">Jackpot</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/Profile">Profile</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/Market">Market</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/Support">Support</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Also, not a good idea to have anything other than `<li>` inside the `<ul>`. You have also omitted a `</a>`.

Comment: I mean like vertically and horizontally, as in lets say I have a box, or in this case a header section. I want my text list in the middle of the box, going across, (x axis, and y axis) and also Praveen, what do you mean anything other than <li> inside my <ul>?

Comment: That's fine, @JasperE. What about the logo? Do you want that too inline with the `<li>`s?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c0094ee260093dee84039af201fd4653 I basically just want my text centered in the given area... Please specify where to add my code to. Sorry I'm a noob at this stuff.

Comment: @JasperE Give `#navcontainer ul {float: right;}`? It would be better if you give the HTML and CSS or a live example or a GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few errors in your markup, I've gone ahead and fixed them for you. All that's required to center your list items is text-align: center if you're positioning them as inline elements.

```
<div id= "navcontainer">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="index" class="page-logo" href="/">
                <img src="slamlogo.png" alt="Logo">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/Jackpot">Jackpot</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Market">Market</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Support">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#navcontainer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #800000;
    text-align: center;
}
#navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#navcontainer ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 40px;
}
#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #800000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruLns221/

Just to further explain the changes, you should only add li elements to an unordered list (ul) so I've nested your logo within a list item. I've closed some unclosed tags off as well.

Comment: What If I wanted a link in the script too? Could I put it in the unordered list as well? Its just an <a href>.

Comment: Plus, your script gives my logo a hover color effect which I didn't want.

Comment: You can omit the first list item from your CSS with a pseudo selector, I've updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ruLns221/1/

Comment: Ughhh I'm starting to give up on this... Can you talk to me through Skype and I can screen share? Idk anymore